# Simple Python Random Number Guesser

Tags: python, random, numbers

I've just written a quick script guessing a random number. 
Though the last line of the script 'Congrats you won etc' isn't running. 
Also in some interpreters it is giving an error 'Failed to run script'.

```
import random 
attempts = 0
secret_number = random.randint(1,100)
isCorrect = False
guess = int(input("Take a guess: ")) 

while secret_number != guess: 
    if guess < secret_number:
        print("Higher...")
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        attempts+= 1 
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print("Lower...")
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        attempts+= 1 
    else:
        print("\nYou guessed it! The number was " ,secret_number)
```

Comment: If the initial `guess` is correct, the loop condition is immediately false and the loop is not executed.

Comment: the else line never executes because the while loop condition gets validated on a correct guess and exits the loop. You can just remove the the else and un-indent that line so it shows after it breaks out of the while

Comment: move the last line out of the while loop

Answer (score 1):

I made a few revisions to your script. Note that its functioning is regulated by the execution flow and no special control statements (e.g. `continue`, `break`) or explicit intervention were necessary to make it logically consistent:

```
import random 


secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = None
attempts = 0

while secret_number != guess: 
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: ")) 
    attempts += 1

    if secret_number == guess:
        print("\nYou guessed it! The number was ", secret_number)
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print("Higher...")
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print("Lower...")
```

I changed:

1. The `isCorrect` variable. I deleted it because it was unused;
2. The way the `guess` variable is initialized. It is `None` before the while statement;
3. The conditional statements inside the while loop;
4. The order in which the input is read from the user inside the while loop.

I recommend to get an intuitive sense of why the script is working.

I tried running it and received the following output:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./test.py
Take a guess: 70
Higher...
Take a guess: 80
Higher...
Take a guess: 90
Higher...
Take a guess: 95
Lower...
Take a guess: 94
Lower...
Take a guess: 93
Lower...
Take a guess: 92
Lower...
Take a guess: 91

You guessed it! The number was  91
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print the line out of the while loop, as your loop will break when secret_number == guess.

```
while ...:
    if: 
        ... 
    elif: 
        ...

print "You guessed it! The number was {0}".format(secret_number)
```